# For annotations user hardcode string or constant for better performance?

Tags: java, android, performance, annotations

In different projects I see that some use hardcoded strings and others constants. 
I cannot find an answer as to which is better for RAM memory, use constants or hardcoded?
i.e.

```
@SerializedName(value = Constants.Annotation.PICTURE_ID)
private int pictureID;
```

or

```
@SerializedName(value = "picture_url")
private String url;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think they are the same. Java compiler replaces all the constants with the value of it. In this case, `PICTURE_ID` will be replaced with "picture_url". So the two methods you suggested are the same at compile time. So it makes no difference when you run it.

However, that is not the end of the story. When you use strong literals, it's called early binding. This binds the value at code writing time. When you want to change all the same string literals at different places, you need to change it one by one. If you use constants however, you just need to change the constant value. Thus, the latter increases maintainability and it is recommended.